# How to replace the list in numpy list?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently working on one project where I need to quantize the image. First, I'm reading the image using skimage, and the shape of it is *(825, 1100, 3)*. Image array looks like this:

```
[[[ 43  78  48]
  [ 43  78  48]
  [ 43  78  48]
  ...
  [  5  24  18]
  [  5  24  18]
  [  4  23  17]]

 [[ 43  78  48]
  [ 43  78  48]
  [ 43  78  48]
  ...
  [  5  24  18]
  [  5  24  18]
  [  4  23  17]]

 [[ 43  78  48]
  [ 43  78  48]
  [ 43  78  48]
  ...
  [  5  24  18]
  [  4  23  17]
  [  4  23  17]]

 ...

 [[ 99 143  45]
  [ 99 143  45]
  [ 98 142  44]
  ...
  [102 145  38]
  [100 146  38]
  [100 146  38]]

 [[ 99 143  45]
  [ 99 143  45]
  [ 99 143  45]
  ...
  [103 146  39]
  [100 146  38]
  [ 99 145  37]]

 [[ 97 142  41]
  [ 98 143  42]
  [ 99 144  43]
  ...
  [100 146  38]
  [ 99 145  37]
  [ 99 145  37]]]
```

Then I apply K-means to quantize the image and decrease the colors in it, and I call that arrary less_colors which also has the same shape of *(825, 1100, 3)*. The output is:

```
[[[ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  ...
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]]

 [[ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  ...
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]]

 [[ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  ...
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]]

 ...

 [[111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  ...
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]]

 [[111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  ...
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]]

 [[111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  ...
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]]]
```

I have another variable called first which is a list that is `[30, 48, 29]`.

I would like to change the row of less_colors array into a different array (let's say [0, 0, 0]) if it contains the array called first.

I have tried NumPy, but my code does not work.

```
less_colors[np.where((less_colors == first).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0]
```

The complete code:

```
import cv2

img = io.imread('dog.jpg')
less_colors[(less_colors[:, :] == first).all(axis=2)] = [0, 0, 0]
io.imshow(less_colors)
plt.show()
```

Comment: so, you want to replace every pixel with value `[30,40,29]` in `less_color` with a black pixel? I don't fully understand your problem. What are you trying to do? Whats wronng with current solution?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I edited my question. The code where I want to change the pixels(array), it does not change and result is same.

Comment: `less_colors[(less_colors[:,:] == first).all(axis=2)] = [0,0,0]`

Comment: Aaron, I tried that version, but it also does not work. Rodrigo, yes it works, but if I want to have let's say [222,211,11] in that case it is gonna throw an error, it works when it is integer(in your case 0)

Comment: @NoobDev not working how? seems to work as described on my computer with some dummy test data..

Comment: @Aaron I got no clue why it does not work when I specify *all*. When I print the new array, the value is same as before..

Comment: `less_colors` array type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, so I assume it has to work

Comment: @Aaron you are rigth. In fact, I deleted my comment to avoid future errors. Why is it still failing @Noob? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: I have updated the code. Could you please check it in your system? The color does not change.

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna also in your case, it will be problem when I want to change the color to [222,222,222] as example.

Comment: It does not update the less_colors array in your answer. Please check it.

Comment: are you sure the value you are trying to replace is actually in your array? I mean, if  you are looking for `[1, 2, 3]`, is there any pixel with value `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Did you run the code I sent? If you test it with any image, you will see it does not change. and yes, I am sure value is there.

Comment: @NoobDev You are the one supposed to provide the minimal data to test on ...

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

This was already answered in comments, however, here goes the complete answer:

```py
less_color[(less_color==first).all(axis=2)] = 0
```

## What's goning on?

`less_color==first` returns a boolean mask which is True only for the indexes where the condition is met. This is a matrix with the same shape as the image.

Next, the `.all(axis=2)` operation make sure that the condition is met for all the channels (the second axis): you want to overwrite **iff** three channels contain same value. This also returns a boolean mask, but now with only two dimensions, telling if each coordinate [i,j] accomplish the criteria at the three channels.

Then, we are using this mask to select only those pixels in the `less_colors` array: `less_color[(less_color==first).all(axis=2)]`

Finally, we assign those pixels with the desired value, overriding them with 0; note that this is equivalent to `[0, 0, 0]` due to numpy's broadcasting mechanism.

### Small working example

```py
import numpy as np

# create a small image with ones
less_color = np.ones((5,5,3))

# change one pixel with a different value
less_color[1,1] = 30, 40, 29

# This other should kep as is, since only 2 out of three match the required value
less_color[2,2] = 30, 40, 290
print(less_color)
print('='*10)


# the following line actually solves the question
less_color[(less_color==[30, 40, 29]).all(axis=2)] = 0

# check it out:
print(less_color)
```

##### Common error:

`less_color[less_color==first] = 0` is not enough since it will also replace pixels with partial-matching, for instance, pixels with values like `[10, 10, 29]` will end up as `[10, 10, 0]` while they must not be changed.

Thanks @Aaron for your original and quickly answer.

Comment: Could you please check my updated code? This version does not work as well.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal working exaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); I'm sure this example can yet be refined (probably you'll find the bug yourself in the process) too much code for me at the moment, and the issue yet is not clear, at least for me.

Comment: Did you check my updated code in the question? I assume you didn't.

Comment: I have edited the question with my code.

Comment: @NoobDev your error is you reverse the color channels here: `red, green, blue = int(color[2]), int(color[1]), int(color[0])`, That color then doesn't show up anywhere because you modified it. When you compare the BGR color against the RGB data, it clearly doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

So you want to map a new value to an old value. For your very case it is:

```py
arr[np.all(arr == old_value, axis=-1)] = new_value
```

But you can create a general function to apply any mapping to any `ndarray` as follows:

```py
def ndarray_apply_mapping(
    arr, mapping, mask_function=lambda arr, target: arr == target
):
    res = arr.copy()
    for old_value, new_value in mapping.items():
        mask = mask_function(arr, old_value)
        res[mask] = new_value
    return res
```

It will work on simpler cases:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
mapping = {1: 10, 3: 30, 5: 50}

res = ndarray_apply_mapping(arr, mapping)

assert np.all(res == [0, 10, 2, 30, 4, 50])
```

But also on more complicated cases as yours.

Let's say you have an array with a limited set of RGB values (or cluster labels resulting from k-means, or whatever):

```py
import numpy as np

H, W, C = 8, 16, 3
vmin, vmax = 0, 255
num_values = 10

values = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, size=(num_values, C))

values_rnd_idxs = np.random.randint(0, num_values, size=(H, W))
arr = values[values_rnd_idxs]

assert arr.shape == (H, W, C)
```

And you have a mapping from some of those values to new values:

```py
new_values = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, size=(num_values // 3, C))

mapping = {tuple(old): tuple(new) for old, new in zip(values, new_values)}
```

You can use this mapping as follows:

```py
res = ndarray_apply_mapping(
    arr,
    mapping,
    mask_function=lambda arr, target: np.all(arr == target, axis=-1),
)
```

Plotting to see the result:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax_old, ax_new, ax_same) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

ax_old.imshow(arr)
ax_new.imshow(res)
ax_same.imshow((res == arr).all(axis=-1), vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="gray")

ax_old.set_title("Old")
ax_new.set_title("New")
ax_same.set_title("Matches")

plt.show()
```

[image: imshow before / after / matches]

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and code, but how it would be applied in my case? My problem is not the same as you mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I misread but isn't it your case but you only have one value to map?

Comment: The core is `mask = mask_function(arr, old_value); res[mask] = new_value` with `mask_function=lambda arr, target: np.all(arr == target, axis=-1)` in your case.

Comment: Not really, that does not answer my question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Maybe you don't see it because variables names are not exactly the same and my code is more general, but it is literally the same as the other answer `less_color[(less_color==first).all(axis=2)] = 0`.

Comment: Btw if you care providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I could show you, but I don't have access to `"dog.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

I should have caught it earlier just from your example data, but `[30, 48, 29]` does not exist in your example data:

```
[[ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  ...
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]
  [ 29  48  30]]

 ...

 [[111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
  [111 137  58]
```

Somewhere along the line you inverted the color channels (RGB to BGR), and tried to compare a BGR color against RGB data. The match and replace line I suggested in the comments only needs a small modification if you want to keep the `first` variable in reverse order:

`less_colors[(less_colors[:,:] == first[::-1]).all(axis=2)] = [0,0,0]`